# Load .env file in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Is there a simple way to automatically load a file containing local configurations into a `Makefile`?

I have a file, `.env`, containing `key=value` pairs on each line:

```
var1=val1
var2=val2
```

Currently I am importing each variable into my `Makefile` manually like this:

```
  var1=$$(grep '^var1=' .env | cut -d= -f2-)
```

This feels clumsy and prone to bugs when adding more variables.

I have also tried adding an extra target to the `Makefile` to read each line of `.env` and pass it to `export`, but values exported in one target are not available to others.

I expect there is a built in feature for doing this in `make`, but I have not been able to find documentation for it.

Comment: Does `include` not do what you want here? Do those values all need to be export specifically to the processes that make runs?

Comment: @EtanReisner yep, include works perfectly - thanks!  I should probably have found that in the docs!!  Add this as an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) `One occasion for using include directives is when several programs, handled by individual makefiles in various directories, need to use a common set of variable definitions (see Setting Variables) or pattern rules (see Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules).`

Comment: See also: [**Makefile include env file**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235223/224425) (Unix & Linux StackExchange)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your include file is comprised entirely of valid make assignments then the [`include` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) is likely what you want here.

> The include directive tells make to suspend reading the current makefile and read one or more other makefiles before continuing. The directive is a line in the makefile that looks like this:
>
> ```
> include filenames…
> ```
>
> filenames can contain shell file name patterns.

Comment: That include would be better wrapped with `ifneq (,$(wildcard ./.env))` because using only `include filename` will provoke an error if the file does not exist and we may have some default values for env vars. There is a very nice post about it in [Lithic Tech's Blog](https://lithic.tech/blog/2020-05/makefile-dot-env)

Comment: If you want to avoid errors when including files that do not exist, you can use """-include filename"""; there is no real need for the wildcard itself for that use case.