# How to load and export variables from an .env file in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

What is the best way to use a `.env` in a Makefile, i.e. loading that file and exporting all variables for subshells in `make`?

It would be great if the proposed solution would work with `make` only, e.g. not using any third party tools. Also `.env` files support multiline variables like:

`FOO="this\nis\na\nmultiline\nvar"`

this is why [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300830/load-env-file-in-makefile) is probably not adequate.

Comment: `include` works.

Comment: Not really. It might load the variables in most cases properly, but it does not automatically export them as environment for commands in sub shells right?

Comment: If you're talking about GNU make, there's probably *some* very complex way to achieve this using the string functions and `$(eval )`, but it doesn't sound like a good idea. There might be a much more straight-forward solution if you would state what's the goal you want to achieve by exporting these variables...

Comment: The idea is to follow the 12 factor app ideas, having an `.env` file that contains all the environment variables needed for build/deployment configuration. Since `make` is the tool that orchestrates the build/deployment, it would be nice if I could easily use this `.env` without external tools.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make does not offer any way to read a content of the file to some variable. So, I consider it impossible to achieve the result without using external tools. However, if I am wrong, I'd be glad to learn some new trick.

So, let's assume there are two files, `.env`, being a technically correct shell file:

```
FOO=bar

BAR="notfoo" # comment
   #comment
MULTILINE="This\nis\nSparta!"
# comment
```

and `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo FOO=${FOO}
echo BAR=${BAR}
echo -e ${MULTILINE}
```

One solution is to include the `.env` file, then make sure variables are exported:

```
include .env

$(eval export $(shell sed -ne 's/ *#.*$$//; /./ s/=.*$$// p' .env))

all:
    ./script.sh
```

Because of different treatment of quotes by shell and make, you will see the quotes in output.

You can avoid that by reprocessing the variables by make:

```
include .env

VARS:=$(shell sed -ne 's/ *\#.*$$//; /./ s/=.*$$// p' .env )
$(foreach v,$(VARS),$(eval $(shell echo export $(v)="$($(v))")))

all:
    ./script.sh
```

but then the multiline variable will become a one-liner.

Finally, you can generate a temporary file to be processed by bash and source it before any command is run:

```
SHELL=bash

all: .env-export
    . .env-export && ./script.sh

.env-export: .env
    sed -ne '/^export / {p;d}; /.*=/ s/^/export / p' .env > .env-export
```

Oh, new lines got messed in this case in multiline variable. You need to additionally quote them.

Finally, you can add `export` to .env using above `sed` command, and do:

```
SHELL=bash
%: .env-export
    . .env-export && make -f secondary "$@"
```

Comment: Alright, I think you convinced me to use an external tool. Thank you for the elaborate answer!

Comment: The whole treatment of quotes in shell vs make makes it really messy. One other solution seems to be to prepend each command with `. .env; `, i.e. `. env; echo $FOO`

Comment: In example given by you `$FOO` is expanded by the same shell sourcing `.env` file. To run `. .env; ./script.sh` variables need to be already exported in `.env` file, to be visisble inside `./script.sh`.

Answer (score 21):

Found this and it worked great:

at top of makefile

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard ./.env))
    include .env
    export
endif
```

Then you have make variables for all your env, for example MY_VAR use as $(MY_VAR)

Comment: this works, but I had to do some googling to understand how ... so for anyone else ... `ifneq` + `wildcard` is a typical way to check a file exists; `include .env` imports `.env` into makefile variables, and `export` without a parameter exports all variables

Answer (score 6):

You can load specific .env file for each target by creating a function and target to use it with other targets when necessary. Here as an sample:

```
define setup_env
    $(eval ENV_FILE := $(1).env)
    @echo " - setup env $(ENV_FILE)"
    $(eval include $(1).env)
    $(eval export)
endef

devEnv: 
    $(call setup_env, dev)

prodEnv: 
    $(call setup_env, prod)

clean:
    rm -rf  bin/

build: clean
    GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/ ./cmd/...

dev: build devEnv
    cd cmd/api && ./../../bin/api
 
migrate-dev-db: devEnv
    sh +x database/migration/migrate.sh dev

migrate-prod-db: prodEnv
    sh +x database/migration/migrate.sh


deploy: prodEnv
    sh +x script/deployment/production/ec2-deploy.sh
```

Comment: Why does the `dev` target depend on `devEnv` and then also immediately call `$(call setup_env,dev)` too?

Comment: @MarkLakata Sorry for the mistake. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample .env and makefile usage:

`.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/my_db_development?sslmode=disable
```

`makefile`:

```
include .env

migrate:
    migrate -source file://postgres/migrations \
            -database $(DATABASE_URL) up
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and here how I solve it.

- First, I recommend checking if the `.env` file exists, otherwise the
  `include` will raise an exception.
- Second, feel free to add the `.env-example` file to your repo.

```
    ENVFILE = .env
    ENVFILE_EXAMPLE = .env-example
    
    # Create the .env file if not exit.
    ifeq ("$(wildcard $(ENVFILE))","")
       $(shell cp $(ENVFILE_EXAMPLE) $(ENVFILE))
    endif
    # Load the environment variables from .env file
    include $(ENVFILE)
    export $(shell sed '/^\#/d; s/=.*//' $(ENVFILE))
```

FYI: this approach does handle comments also, which is not supposed by default by Makefile syntax.

Sanhoj - Thanks